# Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json

Tags: reactjs, debugging

Every time when i change on JSX. This error throw on my terminal and project UI.

> Plugin "react" was conflicted between
>
> "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\projects\end-game-project\sporte\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js"
>
> "BaseConfig » C:\Projects\end-game-project\sporte\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".
> Then when I do CTRL+S on package.json, It temporary fixed.

But how can I permanently fix it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you started your react app in the terminal, it looks like you entered a path using a capital 'P' in C:Projects\end-game-project, even though the actual path does not have a capital 'p'  and should be C:projects\end-game-project (or vice-versa).

Note that some terminals, like the one VS offers, aren't case sensitive, and they will let you 'cd' into folders even if you misuse an upper or lowercase letter.

To fix this, the solution is rather simple. Open the command terminal where you launch your React app and use 'cd..' to navigate out of the project folder, going as far back as your C drive. Then, navigate back to your project folder, this time ensuring you use the correct uppercase and lowercase letters in your file path. Then launch your app again and the problem should be resolved.